# as3scriptinglib (dynamic code loading) is compiling the code but is not executed

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flashdevelop

I have problems implementing https://code.google.com/p/as3scriptinglib/ in my project.

The code is compiled, but it simply is not executed.

```
public function Main():void {
    var loader:CompilerLoader = new CompilerLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(CompilerEvent.INIT, compilerInit);
    loader.load("ESCompilerSWF.swf");
    trace("INIT");
}

private function compilerInit(event:CompilerEvent):void {
    var compiler:ICompiler = event.compiler;
    trace("PREPARE",compiler.initialized);
    var str:String = 'trace("HELLO WORLD");';
    try {
        var script:IScript = compiler.compileAndLoad(str, new ScriptContext(this));
        script.addEventListener(ScriptErrorEvent.SCRIPT_ERROR, trace);
        trace("Script created");
    } catch (e:Error) {
        trace("ERROR", e.message);
    }
    trace("READY");

}
```

And it outputs:

```
INIT
PREPARE true
Script created
READY
```

So, as you can see the code is not executed by as3scriptinglib. 
Help.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The class that execute the script was Garbage Collected, so I change:

```
var script:IScript = compiler.compileAndLoad(str, new ScriptContext(this));
```

to a variable outside the function, like:

```
script = compiler.compileAndLoad(str, new ScriptContext(this));
```

And it works.

:)